# Speed up code in python

Tags: python, algorithm

N,M are taken as input, N items are given initially, these may be marked and exchanged for new ones, such that 1 new item is given for M of these marked items, the problem is to find the maximum number of items that can be marked in this way. For example:

Input : `10 2`
N=10, M=2
Then output is : `10 + 5 + 2 + 1 + 1`
because
first the given 10 (N) items are marked, then all of the 10 are exchanged for 5 new ones (N/M) and marked,
then 4 of these exchanged(1 saved for future) for 2 new ones and marked,
then 2 exchanged for 1 new one, this new one marked and
 along with the 1 saved before exchanged for a new one and marked.

```
Constraints:

1 <= N <= 1000

2 <= M <= 1000
```

This is what i tried:

```
n,m = map(int,raw_input().split())
s = n
aux = 0
while n!=1:
    aux = n%m
    n /= m
    s +=n
    n +=aux
print s
```

But it is too slow to get past the judge. How can I speed it up? Any other algorithms to do this?

Comment: For a minor improvement (probably unnoticeable in practice), you could merge the lines `aux = n%m` and `n /= m` into `n, aux = divmod(n, m)`. But usually the way to speed up simple things like this is to find a smarter algorithm rather than to try to make individual lines run faster.

Comment: Can u suggest a different algorithm?

Comment: How is the judge timing this code? This should be fairly quick in practice.

Comment: @Patrick87 works now.. My termination condition was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n,m = map(int,raw_input().split())
s = n
aux = 0
while n>=m:
    n, aux = divmod(n, m)
    s +=n
    n +=aux
print s
```

The termination condition of the loop was wrong and should be current value < m as we cannot get new items of we have lees than M marked items left with us.